# How to use optional value type (i.e. struct) parameters without using Nullable<T> in WebApi 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-routing

I want action method with optional parameters of value type, but without using Nullable
something like

```
    public string Test2([FromUri] MyKey x = default)
    { ... }
```

When i call this api with /test2?something=42, it is ok, but when I miss any parameter, it throws error

`The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'x' of non-nullable type 'WebApiTst.Controllers.MyKey' for method 'System.String Test2(WebApiTst.Controllers.MyKey)' in 'WebApiTst.Controllers.TestController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.`

It is strange, that naming that parameter (with same name) makes things even worse...

I am using WebApi 2 with just config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

This is my test controller

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // OK - https://localhost:44302/test2?something=22
    // NOK - https://localhost:44302/test2
    [Route("test2")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test2([FromUri] MyKey x = default)
    {
        return "TEST2:" + x;
    }

    // NOK - https://localhost:44302/test3?something=22
    // NOK - https://localhost:44302/test3
    [Route("test3")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test3([FromUri(Name = "x")] MyKey x = default)
    {
        return "TEST3:" + x;
    }
}

public struct MyKey
{
    public static MyKey Empty { get; } = new MyKey();
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[ID={ID}]";
    }
}
```

What is causing this? How to use value-type optional parameters without using Nullable ?

[Edited:] I am using ModelBinder, which will deserialize MyKey from string.
I also tried same example in Asp.net core webapi and it works.

Comment: Sorry but what   public static MyKey Empty { get; } = new MyKey(); means and for? I never met anything like this. To make your struct nullable you just have to mark   public int? ID { get; set; }

Comment: Pls check my last update

Answer (score 1):

It is  a very bad style to make API with query string. MUCH BETTER way is to initiate your MyKey class on creation by default values:

```
public class MyKey
{
public string X {get; set;}
public Property1 {get; set;}
public Property2 {get; set;}

public MyKey()
{
X = "default";
Property1=default1;
Property2=default2;
.....
}
```

and then you can use the action like this

```
 [Route("Test2/{X?}")]
public string Test2(MyKey myKey )
{
return "TEST2: " + myKey.X;
}
```

if X is null, myKey.X will  still have a default value it got on creation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But you are not answering to my question, and I cannot agree with you.
If I want api in terms of data "query", for example GET /api/library/books with optional selection parameters like category, author, title, it is very ugly to just use something like GET /api/library/books/-/-/Crowford. Much better semantics is like GET /api/library/books?author=Crowford.
One of my parameters is something like let say GPS coordinates and I want to use them in form GET /api/library/books?location=[64,92], so I am using struct for it and custom ModelBinder.

Comment: Thank you for asking. In this case I would prefer /api/lilbrary/gpslocation/64/92. In your previous sample I would use api/library/location/Crowford. You can make generic route like this api/library/{type}/{param1?}/{param2?}. Or you can make several concrete routs it is not a big deal. I have some good experience with apis and I prefer this syntax because it is much more clear to use and to test. You can check my other answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731635/can-a-controller-support-a-route-with-variable-string-parameters/64731997?noredirect=1#comment114453801_64731997

Comment: I got your point that .../location/... is better, but I want to provide api with any combination of these parameters, so optional named parameters seems to provide much better semantic than just positioned one. In my example I want to be possible also /api/library/book?author=Crowford&location=[1,2] and so on. If there is, lets say 15 such parameters, it is very unclear, what parameter means what, if it will use positional params like /api/library/book/-/-/-/-/-/[2:4]/-/42/-/-/-/scifi instead of /api/library/book?location=[2,4]?categoryId=42&genre=scifi.

Comment: You will never create such complicated url  by hand. In this case case I would prever create a big ViewModel object with all parameters and send it to API in a request body. In this case your api action will have this syntax [Route("~/api/library")]  public IActionResult GetData([FromBody] MyViewModel viewModel){.....}