# Can a Controller support a route with variable string parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to support routes such as `/route/param1`,  `/route/param1/param2`,  `/route/param1/param2/param3` and so on.

For now I have define in my Controller one route per combination of parameters:

```
    [Route("{path1}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Route1(string path1)
    {
        return await ParsePath(new[] { path1 });
    }

    [Route("{path1}/{path2}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Route2(string path1, string path2)
    {
        return await ParsePath(new[] { path1, path2 });
    }
```

This has 2 major drawback:

- For now I have 8 of these so I can only support up to 8 parameters
- This code is not very DRY if I want to support more parameters

I would prefer to use a method with such signature:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> RouteMultiple(params string[] paths)
    {
        return await ParsePath(queryString, paths);
    }
```

but is this compatible with the `Route` attribute?

Comment: Hi @CamiloTerevinto thanks for your reply. I want to use a GET endpoint with the parameters in the URL as described, so users can change them easily and for SEO purposes

Comment: The middleware avenue sound interesting, would using some middleware make it possible to clean up this code and support the routes as described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
  [Route("{path1?}/{path2?}/{path3?}/{path4?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RouteMultiple(string path1, string path2, ... and so on)
    {
        return await ParsePath(new[] { path1, path2, ... and so on });
    }
```

It works in Postman.

Comment: Thanks! This looks simple and promising, I will try it :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this in a Controller action, because they're not thought for these situations. You can, however, go outside the MVC world and use a middleware directly on the desired path.

Where you configure:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

add another map to your dynamic route:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.Map("Products/{**values}", DynamicPathMiddleware.InvokeAsync);
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Where `DynamicPathMiddleware.InvokeAsync` is a very simple static method like this:

```
public class DynamicPathMiddleware
{
    public static async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var paths = context.Request.Path.Value.Substring("Products/".Length + 1).Split('/');
        // from the question's code
        await ParsePath(paths);

        // and write to the response with
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(paths));
    }
}
```

With the code above, going to /Products/asd/123/asd would return an HTTP 200 with the body `["asd", "123", "asd"]`